# Interested in finding k shortest path in opl cplex by dijkstra algorithm

Tags: dijkstra, cplex

I am interested in finding k shortest path from source node to destination node by dijkstra's algorithm. i have solved the same problem with the help of dvar boolean to declear a boolean variables for the link which can take value 1 if the link is selected for path and 0 otherwise but the problem there this variable calculate the shortest path for each flow which is much time consuming. Now i am interested to get rid of flow conservation constraint and use some type of algorithm for column generation approaches which can resolve the problem at once not to calculate the path for each variable. I am looking forward to hearing from you

Comment: Same question at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=1bdafb0f-4ef9-4608-bd3c-6e1ba1bd0580&ps=25

Comment: Same question at https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=630ee7d5-c9cc-45e0-8eb3-b11fc4c7e9e6&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer#bm630ee7d5-c9cc-45e0-8eb3-b11fc4c7e9e6

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about performance then it is probably not a good idea to attack this problem with a general integer programming solver. As you can see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing), there are dedicated algorithms available to solve the k-shortest path problem efficiently.
If you want to stick with OPL then you could implement those algorithms using OPLScript.